# Sympy plot: pass in list of symbolic expressions

Tags: python, sympy

I have an unknown amount of symbolic expressions created with sympy.

For example:

```
f1 = x
f2 = exp(x)
...
fn = ...
```

Since it's an unknown amount, I cannot simply do: `plot(f1, f2, f3)`, so I would like to pass in a list of symbolic expressions. I cannot figure out how to do this?

Comment: Is the problem that you don't know how to pass in a list of expressions to `plot`, or that you have all these named variables and you don't know how to collect them?  (Right answer: put them into a collection like a list or dict to start with, although there are some hacks.)

Answer (score 5):

Use the [argument unpacking operator](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/), `*`.

```
plot(*[f1, f2, f3])
```

is equivalent to

```
plot(f1, f2, f3)
```

Comment: If they are using the typical Matplotlib `plot()` command, then you cannot simply supply functions as a series of arguments as you are suggesting: http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot

Comment: This question is about [sympy's plot function](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/plotting.html#sympy.plotting.plot.plot), not matplotlib.pyplot.plot.